If the group extension is torsion-free, what about the quotient group?
Suppose that
$$1 \to H \to G \to K \to 1$$
is a short exact sequence (which means that $G$ is an extension of $K$ by $H$). Assume that $G$ is torsion-free. Is $K$ torsion-free? It seems that is not necessarily true, but I cannot find some conditions that makes this true. My case of interest is when $G$ is free, but I would like to know if there is something to general torsion-free $G$

$K$ will contain a torsion element exactly iff there exist $h \in H$ (identified with its image in $G$) and $g \in G \setminus H$ with $g^n = h$ for some $n > 1$, so you should demand that "$H < G$ is closed under roots" (I don't know if this has a name).

Do also note that given such a sequence one would probably expect this to be the exception rather than the norm: for instance, $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \overset{\cdot n}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / n \to 0$ is exact for all $n > 0$, and since every homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is multiplication by some $n$, the only time you get non-torsion out of this is when $n = 1$ and the map is the identity.

In fact every group is the quotient of a free group.

${{{}}}$ I see!
